# ffmpeg with drawtext filenames of diffrent files within a -i concat filelist.txt

Tags: video, ffmpeg, drawtext

with the following script i am able to concatenate multiple video files within a textfile to a single video.

now i want to have the individual names of each source video file displayed in the output video.

here is a example of my source videoList.txt file with filename and filepath

```
# videoList.txt
file 'C:\video_0020.mp4' 
file 'C:\video_0040.mp4' 
file '..'
```

and the windows batch file:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL

SET ffmpeg=C:\ffmpeg\bin
SET inFile=-f concat -i C:\videoList.txt
SET outFile=C:\output.mov

SET codec=-r 24 -vcodec mjpeg -q:v 6
REM videoFilter/filterComplex
SET filterComplex=drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf': text='%%{filenameOfEachVideo}'

REM bring it all together
SET commandline=%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg.exe %inFile% -filter_complex "%filterComplex%" %codec% %outFile%

REM execute command
%commandline%
```

Comment: Do you want it encoded into the video, or will softsubs suffice?

Comment: i want to have the file names burnt into the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. Please check paths and file extenions before use.
I added a lot of comments to make it more clear what the script does. Feel free to use and modifie.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM path to ffmpeg
SET ffmpeg=C:\path\to\ffmpeg\bin
REM source movies from
SET movieSource=C:\path\to\your\mp4\movies
REM tmp dir
SET tmpDir=C:\path\for\tmp\files\and\final\output


REM setup positon, color, background, font for the text overlays
REM filterComplex, quotes have to be escaped! -> \"
REM BITC - Burned In Time Code
SET filterComplexTimecode=drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf': timecode='10\:00\:00\:00': timecode_rate=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(1*lh)-3: fontsize=20: fontcolor=white@0.4: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@0.4: boxborderw=4
REM Date
SET filterComplexDate=drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf': text='%%{localtime\: %%d.%%m.%%Y %%H\\\:%%M}': x=(w-tw-3): y=h-(1*lh)-3: fontsize=20: fontcolor=white@0.4: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@0.4: boxborderw=4
REM Shotname
SET filterComplexShotname=drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf': x=0: y=h-(1*lh)+1: fontsize=20: fontcolor=white@0.4: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@0.4: boxborderw=4:



REM create a list of all files
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir %movieSource%\*.mp4 /b  ^| sort') DO ECHO file '%movieSource%\%%F' >> %tmpDir%\filelist.txt

REM gather more informations for each file
ECHO ; filename, durationInSeconds > %tmpDir%\fileNameDuration.txt

FOR /R %movieSource%\ %%F IN (*.mp4) DO (
  REM Reset current duration to 0 (zero) for each loop
  SET curDuration=0

  REM get the filename without file extenion
  SET fileName=%%~nF

  REM get the duration of a single clip
  REM and write it to a tmp textfile
  %ffmpeg%\ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 %%~fF > %tmpDir%\fileTempDuration.txt
  REM read the textfile again into a variable
  SET /p curDuration=<%tmpDir%\fileTempDuration.txt

  REM write the filename and the duration to a new list of all files
  ECHO !fileName!,!curDuration! >> %tmpDir%\fileNameDuration.txt
)

REM concate a filter complex string for ffmpeg with all clipnames as textlayer with a inpoint and outpoint
SET filterComplexShotnameCombined=
REM floating numbers are not supported by batch, so we need to work-around that
CALL :IntAsFP b=0.000000
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,2* delims=," %%i IN (%tmpDir%\fileNameDuration.txt) DO (
  CALL :IntAsFP a=%%j
  CALL :IntToFP inPoint=!b! 6
  SET /A c=a+b
  SET /A b=c
  CALL :IntToFP outPoint=!c! 6
  REM just to check whats going on...
  ECHO name: %%i   duration: %%j   inPoint: !inPoint!   outPoint: !outPoint!
  SET filterComplexShotnameCombined=!filterComplexShotnameCombined!, !filterComplexShotname! text=%%i: enable=between(t\,!inPoint!\,!outPoint!^^^)
)

REM bringing all together. filter complex for current date, one for the normal timecode, and the actual shotnames.
SET filterComplexCombined=-filter_complex "%filterComplexDate%, %filterComplexTimecode% %filterComplexShotnameCombined%"

REM just to check...
ECHO %filterComplexCombined%
%ffmpeg%\ffmpeg.exe %async% -f concat -i %tmpDir%\filelist.txt %filterComplexCombined% %fps% %codec% %loglevel% %tmpDir%\output.mov


:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

REM Integer to FloatingPoint

:IntAsFP Int=FP
set FP=%2
set %1=%FP:.=%
exit /B


:IntToFP FP=Int digits
set Int=%2
set %1=!Int:~0,-%3!.!Int:~-%3!
exit /B
```